# Que signifie l'expression « Ne fût-ce que » ?

Tags: expressions, subjonctif

On voit souvent cette expression dans les œuvres de littérature. Je n'arrive pas à comprendre l'explication de Littré :

> Ne fût-ce… que, quand ce ne serait que…

Pourrait-on me donner quelques exemples suivi des explications pour éclaircir ce mystère ?

Comment: De nos jours, hors du cas exceptionnel de la littérature, on utilise en général le conditionnel présent: « *ne serait-ce que …* ».

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Voici une petite illustration d'une façon courante d'utiliser cette expression:

> Tu devrais vraiment aller voir [ton ami/ton oncle/le patient], ne fût-ce que quelques instant.

Une traduction en anglais pourrait donner:

> You should really go see your grandma, [even] if only for a few moments.

Dans cette forme, il s'agit de souligner qu'on ne demande pas à son interlocuteur un effort incommensurable, mais plutôt un geste, voire une pensée, une petite action simple.

Suivant le contexte (et le ton), cette expression peut être le signe d'un reproche (la personne ne s'implique pas assez), ou d'une imploration:

> Pourriez-vous nous donner à manger, ne fût-ce qu'une miche de pain?

On l'utilise aussi un peu différemment:

> Cette nouvelle voiture est exceptionnelle, ne fût-ce que par son prix.

Ici, l'expression signifie que le prix n'est qu'un des éléments qui rend cette voiture exceptionnelle – il y en a d'autres (son confort, son moteur, etc.), mais qu'à lui-seul il suffit à qualifier cet engin d'hors norme.

Il me semble que la construction anglaise *if only for* couvre assez bien le *ne fût-ce que* français en général, y compris un côté potentiellement ironique, moqueur ou humoristique dans cette deuxième façon de l'utiliser.

> Henry VIII is a towering figure in British history if only for his height and weight.

([source](http://www.helium.com/items/2099851-king-henry-viiis-legacy)) On pourrait traduire par:

> Le roi Henry VIII est une personnage monumental de l'histoire anglaise, ne serait-ce que par sa taille et son poids.

Answer (score 6):

J'ai cherché dans *Wikiquotes* des exemples de *« Ne fût-ce que »* et son alternative désormais plus courante *« ne serait-ce que »* dans la littérature française. On trouve :

- « Il est nécessaire de les connaître, ne fût-ce que pour les éviter. » — *Les misérables*, Victor Hugo.
- « Faire le poème de la conscience humaine, ne fût-ce qu’à propos d’un seul homme, ne fût-ce qu’à propos du plus infime des hommes, ce serait fondre toutes les épopées dans une épopée supérieure et définitive. » — *idem*
- « Il faudrait essayer d’être heureux, ne serait-ce que pour donner l’exemple. » — Jacques Prévert
- « Il faut aimer ses ennemis, ne serait-ce que parce que cela leur porte sur les nerfs. » — *Les Thanatonautes*, Bernard Werber.

Le sens de ces expressions est celui de ***« même si ce n'est que »***, ou de l'anglais ***“[even] if only”***.

Comment: Son sens est comparable à «quoique» ?