# The meaning of "ne serait-ce que"?

Tags: sens

I have a hard time accurately understanding the meaning of this phrase, beyond a vague grasp of it.

> J'ai du mal à faire confiance aux étrangers. **Ne serait-ce qu**'a cause de ces histoires d'intrus.
>
> Vous allez accepter, de toute façon. **Ne serait-ce que** pour l'or que vous rapportera cette mission.
>
> Ces gens vendraient leur âme pour avoir **ne serait-ce qu**'une bribe d'information sur l'incident.

How to interpret the third example has me particularly puzzled. I can't think of a better way to translate "ne serait-ce que" than into "just".

> These people would do anything to get their hands on **just** some scraps of information about the incident.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ne serait-ce que* is used to introduce a narrowing down of the fact that's been stated. Meaning can slightly vary according to context.

> J'ai du mal à faire confiance aux étrangers. Ne serait-ce qu'à cause de ces histoires d'intrus.
>
> Vous allez accepter, de toute façon. Ne serait-ce que pour l'or que vous rapportera cette mission.

In those sentences as ExteFrench says it is used to introduce the main reason not to trust strangers / to accept the job. ("... if only because...").

> Ces gens vendraient leur âme pour avoir ne serait-ce qu'une bribe d'information sur l'incident.

Here it expresses a limitation, you could easily replace it with *au moins* ou *au minimum* (... "on at least one single piece of news.")

> Ces gens vendraient leur âme pour avoir au minimum une bribe d'information sur l'incident.

Note that in a negative context, meaning differs slightly. It is synonym of *même pas* ("not even").

> Il n'a rien voulu entendre, ne serait-ce que des excuses.

*Ne serait-ce que* is a "conditionnel présent". In very formal register and literature you might find the "subjonctif imparfait" *ne fût-ce que*. See [the answers to this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2106/358) for more.

Comment: I'd like to add two things: 1) you can conjugate it to *subjonctif imparfait* with **ne fût-ce que**, which is very formal language and can be replace by **ne serait-ce** (see http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2106/que-signifie-lexpression-ne-f%C3%BBt-ce-que ) ; 2) you can replace **ne serait-ce que** with **rien que**: '[...] Rien qu'à cause de ces histoires d'intrus.'.

Answer (score 2):

In fact "ne serait-ce que" is used when you want to give only one good reason and that it is implicit that there are many reasons.

For you second question, you do not need to place a "à" right before "cette mission".
What will the mission bring back ? -> gold.

Hope that it helps.

Answer (score 1):

A translation may be: "were it only..." which also uses the conditional and inversion.

> J'ai du mal à faire confiance aux étrangers. **Ne serait-ce qu'à** cause de ces histoires d'intrus.
>
> I find it hard to trust strangers. **Were it only** for this intruder business.
>
> Vous allez accepter, de toute façon. **Ne serait-ce que** pour l'or que vous rapportera cette mission.
>
> You'll accept anyway. **Were it only** for the gold that this mission will bring you.

When used as an object, "but" is close in meaning, as in:

> Ces gens vendraient leur âme pour avoir **ne serait-ce** qu'une bribe d'information sur l'incident.
>
> These people would sell their soul to get **but** a morsel of information on the incident.

Comment: Yes. Or perhaps more commonly, for the first case: "*even if only for just...*"

Comment: Yes that would be more common, but then again "ne serait-ce que" isn't all that common either. The other answers explain the meaning well, I wanted to add a more literal translation.